# How to execute a given data in a post in the header of that web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, youtube

Hi I was just starting building some websites from scratch when I ran into something that requires a bit of help. Well the problem is if suppose I have a youtube video embedded in the post but I wish to display the video in the header section of that particular post url without adding the code manually in the header.

> General Idea: Youtube video embed code is present in post but wish to
>   display it as looped background video in the header without adding the
>   code manually in the header while rendering it from the post on to header so that every post page has a header with embedded video as header while a small part of the video keeps looping in the background

I have no idea how to display that data in the header instead of inside the post although the info lies within the post. I have seen some sort of data tag in html data:post-header but I have no knowledge about it so please if one can provide a solution on how to render the data than it will be very helpful.
[image: Video embedded in the post but I do not wish it to show up there but instead show up as header background]
[image: Video not showing up in the post but instead in the header while a small part of it loops in the background]

Thanks in advance. :) Also a bit of info on the data tag will be very helpful ! :D

Comment: as i understood, what you are looking for is that when the user open the page, the video automatically reproduce?and you want to reproduce it in the header tag??isn't it?

Comment: Yup Micky! The video is embeded in the post but I wish to show up it in the header without manually putting the video in the header. It's like shark is in the water but I wish to show it on the oceans surface.

Comment: i understand now :-D i already answered this, check out :-D

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in your header tag

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="500" height="405" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ID_VIDEO?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

as you may see there is an autoplay part, so this will activate the video when the user comes into your page, and you have to provide the url of the video